# Typescript function that makes the object values as keys and the keys as values

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to create a function that will invert the provided object.

For instance, I have this object

```
{
 a: "aee",
 b: "bee",
 c: "cee"
}
```

I want to make it

```
{
 aee: "a",
 bee: "b",
 cee: "c"
}
```

Using a function as follows:

```
mapSelf(myObject)
```

The logic in JavaScript is straight forward:

```js
function mapSelf(object) {
  const result = {};
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(object)) {
    result[value] = key;
  }
  return result;
}
const test = mapSelf({
  a: 'aee',
  b: 'bee',
  c: 'cee',
})
console.log(test)
// {
//   "aee": "a",
//   "bee": "b",
//   "cee": "c"
// }
```

Doing this in typescript almost works!

```
function mapSelf<const T extends Record<string, string>>(
  object: T
): Record<T[keyof T], keyof T> {
  const result: any = {}
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(object)) {
    result[value] = key
  }
  return result
}

const test = mapSelf({
  a: 'aee',
  b: 'bee',
  c: 'cee',
})
```

However, I am losing the relation between the keys and their values in the final output.

When I try to hover over `H`

```
const H = test.aee
```

I get H inferred as

```
const H: "a" | "b" | "c"
```

I want H to be equal to its corresponding key, in this case, `H` should be inferred as "a"

Comment: You might want to write, nice and big at the top of your question, that you're looking for the output to be *strongly typed* so that each property has a literal type and not just `string`.  Apparently your question is drawing attention from those who either haven't read the question properly or have failed to understand it

Comment: Well `test` is a `Record<"aee" | "bee" | "cee", "a" | "b" | "c">`. You'll want a mapped type not a `Record`.

Comment: @jcalz, alright,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type you're looking for is the [key-remapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) `{[K in keyof T as T[K]]: K}`.  That lets you choose a new key for each property `K` of `T`:

```
function mapSelf<const T extends Record<string, string>>(
    object: T
): { [K in keyof T as T[K]]: K } {
    const result: any = {}
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(object)) {
        result[value] = key
    }
    return result
}

const test = mapSelf({
    a: 'aee',
    b: 'bee',
    c: 'cee',
})
/* const test: {
    readonly aee: "a";
    readonly bee: "b";
    readonly cee: "c";
} */
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwIYAcDKBTANsAHggQGcpEAVRbADymzABMTEAlbYgJ0YLM5jABzADSI+AwQD5JACgBQiRYjgAjAFYcoALkpyAlDoDeiANoBpRAMQBrbAE84wSolQsK5gLoedFgL6JDBSViMDJETmwSEFxtFzA7RABeAN8gxWA4TkQZELCTWztRADdUXBBsD2UnAHl1TQA6Bih+SJlVDWg9PQC0pUUIqJiTErKKpJt7XtS+iKgQTiQB6Kg5VLlc8now5LQsPGAZQL7UHQByVGxsU+FelTOVS+veiDOIR5vfPTkAegAqRA2iC2sSOSgiqEYCFwCQu2B0ACJUPCANy9cGQsDQxAPOGIeEqFFo7AQqEJN64+EQQn+X7fdakOC4bD1XBwQQyYF6IA)